# console.log() not logging to console inside interval

Tags: javascript

I've looked through numerous post and can't seem to find the answer to my problem.

I have a console.log expression in my interval. When the code is ran in the console, it executes flawlessly, but refuses to console.log my string notifying the client sided user that the script is working.

Heres my code with notes:

- initialize likes to 0
- set interval and seconds (in ms)
- define like button
- define next picture button
- if there's a likeButton, click likeButton
- add 1 to likes and log to console the string
- click the arrow to go to new photo

```
let likes = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    const likeButton = document.querySelector('svg[aria-label="Like"]');
    const nextButton = document.querySelector('svg[aria-label="Next"]');
    if (likeButton) {
        likeButton.parentNode.parentElement.click()
        likes++;
        console.log(`You've liked ${likes} post(s)`); 
    }
    nextButton.parentElement.parentNode.click();
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Is it that `if (likeButton) {` is never being fulfilled?

Comment: So what is the error in the console? Is it finding the likeButton  and nextButton?

Comment: Does it log if the `console.log` is moved outside of the `if` block?

Comment: @epascarello The question doesn't mention an error, it's just not logging `You've liked ...` as it should.

Comment: You have a space gap in your selection `'svg[aria-label ="Like"]'`

Comment: @Barmar after answering 1000's of questions of the years, we all know people somehow ignore console errors. Always got to ask it.

Comment: @X999 makes no difference

Comment: @epascarello That's why I ask "Are there any console errors?" Your question seemed to reference errors that had already been mentioned, so I thought you misread.

Comment: Removing everything except the console.log seems to make it work, so its probably the selectors.

Comment: Well, it looks like more about `likeButton` variable never returns `true`

Comment: if I remove the console.log outside of the interval in any way it still doesn't log anything to the console.

Comment: @caleb, post some html.  This stripped down version works:  https://jsfiddle.net/d93cotsy/

Comment: Add a debug statement in the code. Walk through it in a debugger. Verify that the page did not overwrite console.log. Without seeing it happen, if is just people going to be randomly guessing. Maybe go old school and use alert instead of console and see if they trigger.

Comment: I should mention that there is no error given to the console. it just essentially 'skips over' the console.log line.

Comment: what happens if you add `console.log( likeButton );` before your if conditional?  Is it ever true?

Comment: @lucretius if I add the console.log before the conditional, the code still executes, but it's still not true

Comment: So that means `querySelector('svg[aria-label="Like"]');` isn't valid.  If you post some html we'll be able to help you understand why.

Comment: I dont have any html with it. I'm using this to automate liking post on Instagram, so im running the code in the console. I think the selectors are correct because it actually likes the post and goes on to the next post, so its finding the selectors and clicking the right buttons. I could be wrong, and it still could be the selectors. If its finding the right buttons and clicking them could it still potentially be something with the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `inspect source` of a few posts I've looked at on Instagram, it looks like there are two states to the like button.

- `<svg aria-label="Like" />` when the post has not been liked yet.
- `<svg aria-label="Unlike" />`  when the post has been liked by you already.

The problem is that `const likeButton = document.querySelector('svg[aria-label="Like"]');` is returning the entire element as an object, and isn't a true/false value so `if (likeButton) {` will never be true but as @Unmitigated pointed out it can be "truthy."  To determine if the button has been clicked and to eliminate any "truthy wiggle room" you need to look at the attribute on the `likeButton` element.  You can use getAttribute() for this.

```js
let likes = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    const likeButton = document.querySelector('svg[aria-label="Like"]');
    const nextButton = document.querySelector('svg[aria-label="Next"]');
    if (likeButton.getAttribute("aria-label") === "Like")) {
        likeButton.parentNode.parentElement.click();
        likes++;
        console.log(`You've liked ${likes} post(s)`); 
    }
    nextButton.parentElement.parentNode.click();
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Actually, if the element is found, `likeButton` will be truthy.

Comment: That is apparently true https://jsfiddle.net/qt4cj8em/, I have no idea why op's stuff isn't working then.  Might be something to do with session state or page loads?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and contribution. Your solution solved the problem and the number of post are now being logged to the console. Thank you so much for your time and clear explanation of how you got it to work @Lucretius

Comment: oh, ok great!  Check out that fiddle above to demonstrate what @unmitigated was talking about.  Javascripts truthy logic is a bane.